# Break and continue from a loop in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a simple `foreach` loop. However, after `3` has just been completed, I need to run a unique statement, only once. Then continue where I left off. Here is my loop:

```
$foo = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$i;
foreach($foo as $bar):
$i++;
    echo $bar;
endforeach;
```

However, I'm unsure how to say:

```
if $i == 4
>> interject unique code
continue loop
```

Comment: `foreach($foo as $key=>$bar):` Then you can check `if($key == 3)...`

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm still a beginner :)

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, checking the $key does not work if the array is of the form `array('a'=>1,'carl'=>2,14=>79);`. @tymie, several answers have been posted which show correct implementations. However, the notation that @JonathanKuhn is using is extremely useful in many situations. You may want to have a quick look at the manual: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: @MjrKusanagi: Yes, if the array is not numeric or doesn't have a `3` key then it won't work. However, given OPs example array, this will work fine. I was just showing another method to get the job done.

Answer (score 5):

A normal `if` statement should work for you in this case:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($foo as $bar) {
    echo $bar;

    if ($i++ == 4) {
        // do unique code
    }
}
```

This will *only* execute once, when `$i` is `4` (unless you explicitly set `$i` somewhere other than the `$i++` in your loop).

Answer (score 3):

Use the $i variable you have here.

```
$foo = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$i;
foreach($foo as $bar):
    echo $bar;

    if ($i++ == 4)
    {
        // 1-off code goes here
    }
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use a simple if statement

```
foreach($foo as $bar):
    $i++;
    if($i==4) {
      // run unique statement
    }
    echo $bar;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Using

```
  $foo = array(1,2,3,4,5);

    $i = 0;
    foreach($foo as $bar):
    $i++;
       if($i=='4'){
          //interject unique code
           continue;
        }
        echo $bar;
    endforeach;
```

When $i will reach to 4 only code in if block before continue will be executed and loop will conitnue for next values.

Comment: Thanks, what would happen if the continue was removed?

Comment: whole loop will be executed in that case.  only the code between the if block will be executed when condition is satisfied..

Comment: It's not good practice to check equality between a string and an integer, especially in this way. Why not instead use `if($i===4){...`

Answer (score -1):

Just place an if statement inside your foreach, it will only be used after the third cycle.

```
$foo = array(1,2,3,4,5);

// Your array key will give you your iteration number
foreach($foo as $key => $val):
{

    echo $bar;
    if $key == 3
    {
        echo "I'm in the fourth iteration";
        //Or any other code
    }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering that too. I would expect that person to at least voice his/her complaint in a comment.